# GS1-128 barcode with ZPL does not put the AI in ()

Tags: barcode, zpl, gs1-128

i was expecting this command

```
^FO15,240^BY3,2:1^BCN,100,Y,N,Y,^FD>:>842011118888^FS
```

to generate a
    (420) 11118888

interpretation line, instead it generates

~n42011118888

anyone have idea how to generate the expected output?

TIA!

Joey

Answer (score 1):

If the firmware is up to date, **D** mode can be used.

^BCo,h,f,g,e,m

```
^XA
^FO15,240
^BY3,2:1
^BCN,100,Y,N,Y,D
^FD(420)11118888^FS
^XZ
```

> D = UCC/EAN Mode (x.11.x and newer firmware)
>   This allows dealing with UCC/EAN with and without chained
>   application identifiers. The code starts in the appropriate subset
>   followed by FNC1 to indicate a UCC/EAN 128 bar code. The printer
>   automatically strips out parentheses and spaces for encoding, but
>   prints them in the human-readable section. The printer automatically
>   determines if a check digit is required, calculate it, and print it.
>   Automatically sizes the human readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `^BC` command's "interpretation line" feature does not support auto-insertion of the parentheses. (I think it's safe to assume this is partly because it has no way of determining what your data identifier is by just looking at the data provided - it could be 420, could be 4, could be any other portion of the data starting from the first character.)

My recommendation is that you create a separate text field which handles the logic for the parentheses, and place it just above or below the barcode itself. This is the way I've always approached these in the past - I prefer this method because I have direct control over the font, font size, and formatting of the interpretation line.

Comment: hi! this is the route that I took. thanks for confirming though.